# amp-form Form submission failed: Error: HTTP error 406​

Tags: amp-html

Im using this form as my website search bar and I am looking to convert my website to amp, but I get this error message [amp-form] Form submission failed: Error: HTTP error 406​​​ and i dont know how to fix it

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
<form action-xhr="https://www.website.com/index.php?page=search"  method="POST">
    <button class="searchButton" type="submit" name="submit-search"></button>
    <input class="searchInput" type="text" maxlength="20" name="search" placeholder="search...">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the amp, it's like the local server configuration issue, did you add already amp CORS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm  get this error also. The solution was, after many hours to call to hosting provider and resolve the problem with them. The explanation was that your domain IP should be white-listened.